# Fix overexposed area in the image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to fix the bottom right area of the fingerprint image that is overexposed which make harder to see the ridge. I have tried to divide the image into 4 sub-images and apply histogram equalization to each one but the result is quite bad, it appears the line on the edge of the sub-image.

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AP7J.jpg) [Image after applied histogram equalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzhPk.jpg)

Here is my code of histogram equalization:

```
img = cv.imread('fingerptint.jpg', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

dst = cv.equalizeHist(img)

cv.imwrite('fingerprint_hist.jpg', dst)
```

Comment: Have you tried gamma correction?

Comment: @eldesgraciado the overexposed area still the same when using gamma correction

Comment: You can try Retina method, check here please: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/bioinspired/doc/retina/index.html

Comment: Use adaptive thresholding

Comment: @dhuy If you use Retina (as suggested above) for fixing overexposed images and manage to successfully configure the parameter XML file that it needs, please report back!

Comment: @eldesgraciado I have not tried the Retina method yet, but I used skimage.filters.threshold_local and applied Gaussian filter to the original image then I used this open-source code (https://github.com/Utkarsh-Deshmukh/Fingerprint-Enhancement-Python), it improves a lot. There are more ridges appear. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV's [Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) is not originally meant to fix this, but it produces an image with almost no overexposure and some processing artifacts as downside. Depending on the kind of processing that you are using in later steps, it could be useful.

```
import cv2
import urllib
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

req = urllib.request.urlopen('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AP7J.jpg')
arr = np.asarray(bytearray(req.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(arr, -1)


img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

img_th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
    img_gray,
    255,
    cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY,
    11,
    1
)


plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(img_gray, 'gray')
plt.title('Original Image')
plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(img_th, 'gray')
plt.title('Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding')
plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

[image: Adaptive thresholding]